# unity - How to load sprite from JSON?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

i know how to load text, but idk how to load sprite/pictures from json.

```
 private string mygameDataFileName = "TSdatabase.json";
```

> Here is my code to connect the JSON to my game

```
private void myLoadGameData() //LOAD THE DATA
{
    string myfilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, mygameDataFileName); //I THINK THIS IS THE PATH OF THE FILE
```

Assuming that if the file exists then it will find the path of it.

```
    if (File.Exists(myfilePath))
    {

        string mydataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(myfilePath); // READ THE FILE
        TSGameData myloadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TSGameData>(mydataAsJson);  // TSGAME DATA IS A ANOTHER SCRIPT THAT HAVE AN ARRAY FOR THE DATA
        myRoundData = myloadedData.myRoundData;

    } //myRoundData IS A VARIABLE THAT HOLDS THE ARRAY OF TSROUNDDATA TO GET THE DATA
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    } 
}
```

> Here is my JSON file script

```
    {
  "myRoundData": [
    {
      "name": "Signs",
      "timeLimitInSeconds": 59,
      "pointsAddedForCorrectAnswer": 5,
      "questions": [
        {
          "questionImage": "NoentryPlate",
          "questionText": "What is this?",
          "answers": [
            {
              "answerText": "Traffic Lights",
              "isCorrect": true
            },
            {
              "answerText": "Traffic Signs",
              "isCorrect": false
            },
            {
              "answerText": "None of the above",
              "isCorrect": false
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

}

Comment: Your json load code will not work on Android. Fix that. Read your other question

Comment: @Programmer I would be interested in understanding why exactly this code does not work on Android. Can you give some details? Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will loop through all of the questions in the myRoundData object and create a new gameObject with a SpriteRenderer component and assign the loaded sprite to the renderer. You may need to change the data type of the `CreateImages` parameter to match the data type of the `questions` property in the myRoundData object.

```
private List<GameObject> QuestionImageObjects = new List<GameObject>();

private void myLoadGameData() //LOAD THE DATA
{
    string myfilePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, mygameDataFileName); //I THINK THIS IS THE PATH OF THE FILE
    if (File.Exists(myfilePath))
    {
        string mydataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(myfilePath); // READ THE FILE
        TSGameData myloadedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<TSGameData>(mydataAsJson);  // TSGAME DATA IS A ANOTHER SCRIPT THAT HAVE AN ARRAY FOR THE DATA
        myRoundData = myloadedData.myRoundData;

        CreateImages(myRoundData.questions);
    } //myRoundData IS A VARIABLE THAT HOLDS THE ARRAY OF TSROUNDDATA TO GET THE DATA
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Cannot load game data!");
    }
}

private void CreateImages(List<Question> questions)
{
    //The two while loops below allow existing image gameobjects to be reused

    // Destroy excess images
    while(QuestionImageObjects.Count > questions.Count)
    {
        Destroy(QuestionImageObjects[QuestionImageObjects.Count - 1]);
        QuestionImageObjects.RemoveAt(QuestionImageObjects.Count - 1);
    }
    // Create missing images
    while(QuestionImageObjects.Count < questions.Count)
    {
        GameObject image = new GameObject("Question Image " + QuestionImageObjects.Count);
        image.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        QuestionImageObjects.Add(image);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < questions.Count; i++)
    {
        QuestionImageObjects[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(questions[i].questionImage);
    }
}
```

Comment: CreateImages(myRoundData.questions);              questions is an error what should i do?

Comment: private void CreateImages(List<Question> questions)   CreateImages is also an error

Comment: Replace `List<Question>` with whatever the datatype is for the list of questions in your `myRoundData` object. That should fix both errors. In the future, provide the errors you are getting. It makes it very difficult to provide valuable feedback when we have to make assumptions.